# Is there a hotkey that would turn the screen black?

Tags: windows-7, hotkeys, dell-optiplex

When I was typing on windows7 (Dell OptiPlex 9020, desktop) all the suddenly the screen went black as if I accidentally stumbled on a hotkey-combination that would have that effect. I verified that it isn't the monitor cable that was disconnected (it looses signal if I remove it and regains signal when I reinsert it), also it's not that the monitor is turned off. It's just black (no mouse pointer or nothing).

Is there a keycombo that might explain this behavior? And if that's the case which keycombo returns the system to normal?

I have not (knowingly) been modifying the hotkeys (although I changed the layout using the Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator).

Comment: I don't think there is any shortcut to do this... Usually you would need to actually [create a shortcut/hotkey](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/create-a-shortcut-or-hotkey-to-turn-off-the-monitor/) to do this. Win+P switches the display mode, could that be it?

Comment: Desktop or laptop (I know you said cable implying desktop but for clarity...) ?

Comment: It's a desktop.